# matlab 3d projection image

Tags: image, matlab, projection

I'm doing a image 3D projection, but when I use the iwarp function the result is a multidimensional matrix, I'm using:

```
color1 = imread('color1.jpg') % 480x640x3 image RBG

%4X4 projection matrix
Mx = makehgtform('xrotate',-0.01970);
My = makehgtform('yrotate',0.01729);
Mz = makehgtform('zrotate',-0.00717);
M = Mx*My*Mz;
M(1,4) = -28.54007;
M(2,4) = -2.00470;
M(3,4) = 4.37353;
T = affine3d(M);
%Do transform
Color_Rectified = imwarp(color1,T); %485X644x24
```

At the end, the Color_Rectified size is 485X644x24, the idea is to get the image rotated/translated in X,Y,Z and RGB, how to do this?

Comment: What is `A` in `T = affine3d(A)`?

Comment: Sorry, is M, there is fixed.

Comment: What results are you expecting to get by performing a 3d rotation on a 2d image?

Comment: The result that I expected is an image projected into another camera coordinate system, the M matrix is the extrinsic parameters for camera1 into camera2.

Comment: For that you need a 3d image with depth information. All you're doing with a 2d image is rotating a 2d plane in 3d space. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: I have the depth image from IR kinectcamera, the RGB image doesn't fit with the IR, I did the calibration for both cameras, after I found the transformation matrix between 2 cameras, and then I thought transform the RGB image to fit into the IR image.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with kinect depth maps, but you might want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757940/processing-kinect-depth-data-in-matlab) and the link in the comments.

Comment: No, that's no what I'm searching for, thank you for you time!